# bind-html-compile lacks proper teardown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### $onChanges is still called after $scope.$destroy()

I have a sidebar where different forms appear in it, depending on a clicked button. Each form is represented by a component. It is a bit complicated that I cant share a working code sample (it is also production code). But I will try to explain it as best I could.

I use [`bind-html-compile`](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile) to include the different form components inside the sidebar. like this

```
 <div bind-html-compile="$ctrl.someEditForm"></div>
```

The form component includes data binding, so `$ctrl.someEditForm` could look like

```
<price-edit-form some-data="$ctrl.someData"></price-edit-form>
```

In each from component I use `$onChanges` to set things up in the form. Now, when I click on a different button, `$onChanges` is called for the old button as well, which is understandable since I am also binding the same `some-data="$ctrl.someData"` to the newly clicked button form, so the change will propagate to the old one. This however causes a lot of scopes to be created and stay alive in the project even after they are no longer needed. I need to somehow clean up and destroy these old scopes. I called `$scope.$destroy();` to destroy the scope and I think it gets destroyed since I get `$$destroyed: true` when printing the scope, But `$onChanges` is still called and the scope somehow is still alive.

I also tried to follow the advise [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2706-always-trigger-the-destroy-event-before-removing-elements-in-angularjs-directives.htm) to remove the elements, but since the new edit form appears in the place of the old one, the old one is no longer in the DOM.

I am really sorry for the lack of shared code or the poor explanation (I am still a newbie to Angularjs) but I am kinda of desperate here and have no further things to try. I hope this was sufficient enough to explain the problem.

A further note, it seems that the only time that all created components are truly destroyed is when the sidebar is closed (the only time that the form component `$onDestory` is triggered)

Comment: Really hard to understand the cause of the problem, did you try to use `$event.stopPropagation();` after the button is clicked? Or you can write inside DOM: `ng-click="onClickMethod();$event.stopPropagation();"`

Comment: sorry again, but I dont think `$event.stopPropagation();` will help, since the click event needs to travel up to a parent component then down to the sidebar component.

Comment: well, if so, it is too broad, you can write a demo, some plunker and reproduce the problem. I'm not sure if someone able to help you based on the info you provided.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788721/angular-1-5-components-difference-between-ondestroy-scope-destroy) helps to understand the scope vs controller destruction.

Comment: The problem is with the [bind-html-compile](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile) directive. It is only good for compiling once. Subsequent compiles don't destroy old watchers from previous compiles.